# data attributes in li class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, haml

I have this code in my model:

```
def features_to_html_class  
   "mix #{bedrooms} #{region.name}  #{categories.map{|cat|cat.name}.join(' ')}"
end
```

In my view this

```
- @regions.each do |region|
   - @houses.where(region_id: region.id).each do |house|
     %li{:class => house.features_to_html_class }
```

The HTML output is this:

```
<li class='mix 3 umbria price_range-1 villa_with_pool '>
```

This work fine but now i want to add data attributes "data-sort" and "data-order" to the li class. So i have this HTML output

```
<li class="mix 3 umbria price_range-1 villa_with_pool" data-sort="data-name" data-order="desc">
```

How must i change the features_to_html_class method to realize this?

Thanks...remco

Comment: try  `%li{:class => house.features_to_html_class,  data-sort:  "data-name", data-order: "desc"}`

Comment: Are these values (`'data-name'` and `'desc'`) fixed or do you get them dynamically?

Comment: thanks...the values are dynamically

Comment: then you have to create separate method for that

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
%li{class: house.features_to_html_class, data: {sort: 'data-name', order: 'desc'}}
```

**Update**

Since your data values are dynamic, you could change your method to provide the whole attributes hash:

```
def features_to_html_attributes  
  {
    class: "mix #{bedrooms} #{region.name} #{categories.map{|cat|cat.name}.join(' ')}",
    data: {sort: 'data-name', order: 'desc'}
  }
end
```

And assign it via:

```
%li{features_to_html_attributes}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add new attributes in Haml you just have to pass them as hash ('attribute_name' => 'value')

Following should do

```
- @regions.each do |region|
   - @houses.where(region_id: region.id).each do |house|
     %li{:class => house.features_to_html_class, "data-sort" => "data-name", "data-order" => "desc"}
```

Edit:

Why your change in method 'features_to_html_class' can not be used in the view, because
you have directly written it class attributes(the value appended in the class of li element)

`%li{:class => house.features_to_html_class }`